# SQL Notes: Hackerrank The Report Query how to save the subquery variable

Tags: mysql

Problem:(Link [https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-report/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen][1])

You are given two tables: Students and Grades. Students contains three columns ID, Name and Marks.

Grades contains the min mark and max mark based on which grades are assigned.

Ketty gives Eve a task to generate a report containing three columns: Name, Grade and Mark. Ketty doesn't want the NAMES of those students who received a grade lower than 8. The report must be in descending order by grade -- i.e. higher grades are entered first. If there is more than one student with the same grade (8-10) assigned to them, order those particular students by their name alphabetically. Finally, if the grade is lower than 8, use "NULL" as their name and list them by their grades in descending order. If there is more than one student with the same grade (1-7) assigned to them, order those particular students by their marks in ascending order.

Write a query to help Eve.

My Query which passes the testcase but its redundant , I Want to save the subquery variable

```
SELECT 
    IF( (SELECT G.GRADE FROM GRADES AS G 
        WHERE S.MARKS BETWEEN G.MIN_MARK AND G.MAX_MARK) < 8 , "NULL",S.NAME)
    ,(SELECT G.GRADE FROM GRADES AS G 
          WHERE S.MARKS BETWEEN G.MIN_MARK AND G.MAX_MARK)
    , S.MARKS 
FROM STUDENTS AS S 
ORDER BY (SELECT G.GRADE FROM GRADES AS G 
          WHERE S.MARKS BETWEEN G.MIN_MARK AND G.MAX_MARK) DESC
          , S.NAME;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For SQL Server:**

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN G.Grade >7 THEN S.Name ELSE NULL END) AS NAME, 
G.GRADE,
S.MARKS
FROM STUDENTS S
JOIN GRADES G ON S.MARKS BETWEEN  G.MIN_MARK and G.MAX_MARK
ORDER BY G.GRADE DESC, S.NAME, S.MARKS;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions variables like this:

```
Set @mark := (SELECT G.GRADE FROM GRADES AS G  WHERE S.MARKS BETWEEN G.MIN_MARK AND G.MAX_MARK);
SELECT 
    IF( @mark < 8 , "NULL",S.NAME)
        ,@mark sortvalue
        , S.MARKS 
FROM STUDENTS AS S 
ORDER BY sortvalue DESC
          , S.NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(GRADE <8,'NULL',NAME), GRADE, MARKS 
FROM 
    (SELECT G.GRADE as GRADE, NAME, MARKS 
    FROM 
     GRADES AS G, STUDENTS AS S WHERE MARKS BETWEEN G.MIN_MARK AND G.MAX_MARK
    )SUB
ORDER BY GRADE DESC, NAME ASC, MARKS ASC;
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: Its better to add explanation of your code in answer in accordance to the question

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer...

```
SELECT IF(g.Grade<8, NULL, s.Name), g.Grade, s.Marks 
FROM Students AS s JOIN Grades AS g ON s.Marks BETWEEN g.Min_Mark AND g.Max_Mark 
ORDER BY g.Grade DESC, s.Name, s.Marks;
```

Comment: Please add more details to your code and how does it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

For mysql

```
 select 
    CASE 
        WHEN g.Grade < 8 THEN NULL
        ELSE S.Name
    END as Name ,
   g.grade,s.marks from 
   Students s
   INNER JOIN grades g on s.marks >= g.Min_Mark AND s.marks <= g.Max_Mark
   ORDER BY g.grade DESC, s.Name, s.marks
```

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server

select
(case when g.grade < 8 Then null else s.name end) name,
g.grade ,s.marks from students s join grades g on (s.marks >= g.min_mark and s.marks <= g.max_mark) order by grade desc,name asc,(case when grade< 8 then marks end)

Comment: When by using where

Select name,grade,marks from (select
(case when (select grade from grades where s.marks between min_mark and max_mark) < 8 Then null else s.name end) name,marks,
(select grade from grades where s.marks between min_mark and max_mark) grade
from students s) AS A
order by grade desc,name asc,
(case when grade < 8 then marks end)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

WITH CTE AS(
SELECT Students.ID, Students.Name, Students.Marks, (SELECT Grade FROM Grades WHERE Students.Marks >= Grades.Min_Mark AND Students.Marks <= Grades.Max_Mark) AS Grade
FROM Students
)

SELECT (CASE WHEN Grade < 8 THEN NULL ELSE Name END) AS Name, Grade, Marks
FROM CTE
ORDER BY Grade DESC, Name ASC;

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```sql
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN GRADE<8 THEN NULL ELSE NAME END AS NAME , GRADE, MARKS
FROM GRADES AS G
INNER JOIN STUDENTS AS S
ON S.MARKS BETWEEN G.MIN_MARK AND G.MAX_MARK
ORDER BY G.GRADE DESC, S.NAME, S.MARKS;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).